# Read variable inputs and replace the template file with variable values

Tags: variable, output

In a linux shell scripts, I am reading input for some variable values.  Based on these Variable values, I need to change template file with the input.

For example.

I have a file  hello.txt with the contents

--- Template file hello.txt ---

```
Hello V_NAME
  Welcome V_NAME to the team.
Thanks
```

---

From a shell script,  I read V_NAME variable **John**

```
#!/bin/sh
....
....
read -p "Enter Candidates Name : "  V_NAME
....
exit
```

Then based on the V_NAME the hello.txt should now look like .....

--- Template file hello.txt ---

```
Hello **John** ,
  Welcome **John** to the team.
Thanks
```

---

Appreciate you help.

Thanks
-Naveed-

Comment: Do you want the "template" file which you call "hello.txt" to actually change, or do you want to generate a **new** file based on the template?

Comment: Yes Sir ,  I want template file to change as I will be copying this file from template directory to new location and modifying it.. so my original template will be preserved.

Answer (score 1):

The example seems to be a form letter, so it is not expected that there will be unusual characters to deal with. The `sed` command will be fine, e.g.

```
#!/bin/bash
...
read -p "Enter Candidates Name : "  V_NAME
read -p "Enter Candidates start date : "  V_STARTDATE
sed "s=V_NAME=$V_NAME=g;s=V_STARTDATE=$V_STARTDATE=g" ../template/hello > hello.$V_NAME
...
```

This will break if the candidates name or start date contains an `=` sign.
This assumes that the templates are in another directory.

Another approach would be to use a `here` document and embed the template in the script

```
#!/bin/bash
...
read -p "Enter Candidates Name : "  V_NAME
read -p "Enter Candidates start date : "  V_STARTDATE
cat > hello.$V_NAME <<EOF
Hello $V_NAME
  Welcome $V_NAME to the team. I see you will be starting on $V_STARTDATE.
Thanks
EOF
...
```

and let the shell do the substitutions.

Comment: sed command seems to be working great.   really appreciate  prompt response.

Comment: If the answer is helpful, then you can vote it up. If, after a couple of days, it is the best answer and solves your problem then you can "accept" the answer. Only one answer can be accepted at a time, and it is best to not rush to accept as it tends to discourage others from proposing answers. You can can however change which is your accepted answer.